# excel no me toma los valores con decimal

Tags: excel, vba

estoy teniendo un inconveniente con Excel y los macros.
tengo una tabla en la cual coloco valores reales, es decir valores como 8,5, y al momento de sumarlos o restarlos me los convierte a enteros. Hice un msgbox del value que trae cell().value y en ese momento en lugar de mostrarme 8,5 me muestra 8, Calculo que por ahi esta el problema pero no se como hacer para solucionarlo. por las dudas aclaro, en la tabla he formateado las celdas como decimal con 1 digito detras de la coma, y en el codigo declaro las variables como Long. Donde puede estar el error?

desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: Tabla]

```
Sub Calcular_Saldos()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long    
Dim Vac_Inicial_al As Long
Dim Comp_Inicial_al As Long 
Dim Vac_Saldo_Al As Long
Dim Comp_Saldo_Al As Long   
Dim count_al As Long
Dim count1_al As Long
Dim count2_al As Long  
Dim aux As Long


'Saldos Iniciales
Vac_Inicial_al = CLng(Cells(10, 3).Value)
Comp_Inicial_al = CLng(Cells(10, 2).Value)
  
     
For i = 1 To Rows.count
    
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Alesio" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    'hasta aca me reconoce el nombre del tecnico
        
        For j = 1 To Columns.count
            'Compensatorios tomados
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 255) Then
                aux = CLng(Cells(i, j).Value)
                MsgBox (aux)
                MsgBox (count_al)
                count_al = count_al + CLng(Cells(i, j).Value)
                MsgBox (count_al)
            End If
            'compensatorios ganados
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 230, 153) Then
                count1_al = count1_al + CLng(Cells(i, j).Value)
            End If
            'vacaciones
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180) Then
                count2_al = count2_al + 1#
            End If
            
        Next j
    End If
                 
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Vac_Saldo_Al = Vac_Inicial_al - count2_al
Comp_Saldo_Al = Comp_Inicial_al - count_al + count1_al  


Cells(10, 36).Value = Comp_Saldo_Al
Cells(10, 37).Value = Vac_Saldo_Al
```

End Sub

Comment: Veo que conviertes el valor de las celdas a `CLng` que no deja de ser un entero. Deberías utilizar por ejemplo el `CDbl` para tomarlo como `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Todas tus variables están declaradas de tipo `Long`, que solamente admite números enteros.

Además, la instrucción `Clng` fuerza un valor al entero más próximo.

Deberías trabajar con datos tipo `Single` o `Doble`.

[Tipo datos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo antes de la variable la función FormatNumber, en el primer parametro indica la variable a la que le vas a asignar la función y en el segundo el numero de decimales que quieres ver. Te pongo un ejemplo:

Vac_Saldo_Al = FormatNumber (Vac_Inicial_al - count2_al, 2)

Comp_Saldo_Al = FormatNumber (Comp_Inicial_al - count_al + count1_al, 2)